# android soap calling exception

Tags: java, soap, exception

Hi I have to developed android login with mysql database connection using soap webservices.

its successfully worked my (**localhost/phpmyadmin**)

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androidlogin","root","");
```

But it is doesn't worked on my dev site:  (**dev.www.com/phpmyadmin**)

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://dev.www.com:3306/login","mm2","mm5");
```

i have used above code means am getting following error.please give me how can i resolve this error.

Am getting below error:

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception:      java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out

 ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

 java.net.SocketException
 MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out

 STACKTRACE:

 java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:143)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:225)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1805)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
 at com.xcart.Login.authentication(Login.java:16)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
 at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
 at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)


  ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1875)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
  at com.xcart.Login.authentication(Login.java:16)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
  at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
  at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
  at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: check that you can access your mysql server from the command line first: mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=mypass mydb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a code problem.  It is something in your environment so I am not sure how much anyone here can help you.  Here are a couple of hints.  The exception message is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
```

This rules out a few things. If you were able to access host www.dev.com but mysql was not running, you would have gotten `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`.  If you mistyped the address (ex. www.dev.comm) you would have gotten `java.net.UnknownHostException: <host name>`.

Unfortunately you got the timed out error. This means that the host name was successfully resolved to an address, but when you tried to connect to the address, you got absolutely no response whatsoever from the computer. Which normally means one of two things:

- someone turned off the computer
- there is a firewall turned on between you and the computer and the firewall is not allowing tcp connections on port 3306.

I'm guessing it's the firewall.  Good luck. Hope this helps.